# Can't find old HP bios setup

Tags: bios, ftp, hp-pavilion, setup

I'm trying to find the old version( version F.33) of bios for my HP laptop
The product name is HP Pavilion 15-cc1xx
Sepcs: Intel i5-8250U
8gb ram
Laptop name 15-cc152od

I actually know to site where hp has all setups ftp://ftp.hp.com/pub/softpaq

But, I can't find my bios version setup. If you know a site that keeps track of all hp setup releases with file names please help

Answer (score 3):

I found your bios update [here](https://support.hp.com/in-en/drivers/selfservice/hp-pavilion-15-cc100-laptop-pc/16842299). There is a subtab with previous versions, there you find it.

I would not recommend to download a bios from a website other than your manufacturers.

Comment: Hey thanks for replying, I was actually trying to downgrade my BIOS version cause right after update I'm having certain issues. But the setup which I have is not installing although I've downloaded it from HP site itself, I even tried installing from USB(outside windows). Does HP restrict downgrading the BIOS?

Comment: I don't know but it wouldn't make a lot of sense. In my bios I have a tab for updating the bios from usb. You should check there, else, you can find a guide here https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c00042629 If this is your first time for a bios update, I would recommend writing these instructions down and/or have a second device at hand In case something goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I recently got to know from an hp employee that they restrict downgrading the bios update if it has security improvements. That's why I couldn't downgrade it.